# How to reduce the vertical distance between two divs without reducing the size of the background

Tags: html, css

how do you reduce the spacing between two divs (vertically) without affecting the background behind it. currently what I have is shown below:

```
<div class="col-auto d-flex justify-center-center flex-grow-1">
  <div :class="selected ? 'bg-primary' : 'bg-secondary'">
    <div class="test">
      <u-button icon color="transparent" @click="toggle">
        <u-icon :icon="icon" color="white"/>
      </u-button>
      <small class="ind">Testing</small>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <small class="ind" style="font-size: 9px;">HIDING</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.test {
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-bottom: -10%;
}
```

My problem here is that even though I've managed to reduce the vertical spacing between the two divs (The icon and the text "hiding" with the class "test") the blueish green background also becomes smaller, show below:

[image]

I should mention that the blue/green background comes from `bg-secondary`. How can I reduce the spacing between the icon and the text "hiding" without background size?

Comment: You could set the height of the parent container to auto.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you create a snippet of your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: try `line-height: 0.5` to second `<div>` tag

Comment: That removes the blue/green background colour completely.

Comment: @Mark try `position: relative; top: -10px;` to second `<div>` tag. Try to give top value of your wish.